# brew services restart httpd wont reload apache config

Tags: apache, homebrew

Macos Monterey, Apache 2.53

When I run either

```
brew services restart httpd
```

or

```
brew services restart apache2
```

The config files will not be reloaded

Only

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

works. What wrong with homebrew?

Comment: It looks like you're using the default Apache on Mac. We need more information, though.

Run the following commands separate, and add the ***anonymized*** output to your question please:

```httpd -v or /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -v```

```ps -ef | grep apache```

```ps -ef | grep httpd```

Comment: No. It's homebrew Apache

Comment: Did you run that command above? or did you get it to work?